# Retain select field value after saving

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am struggling to show the selected value in the dropdown after saving.

I have a metabox with a number of select fields in a custom post type that shows a list of posts from other custom post types. On selecting the desired option the value is saved to the database. However, the value is not being retrained in the select field on the back-end after saving.

The data is definitly being saved as I can display it in my template.

I first tried using repeater fields however the result was unreliable, so I stripped out the code and put in basic select fields.

This is my code.

```
case 'list_post':
$my_meta =  get_post_meta($post->ID,'ajax_destination', true);
if (!empty($my_meta)){
$ptitle = get_the_title($my_meta);
$term = get_term_by('name', $ptitle, 'country_tag');
$subcategory_id = $term->term_id;
    $items = get_posts( array (
        'post_type' => $field['post_type'],
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title', 
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'country_tag',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $subcategory_id)
        )
    ));
    echo '<td><select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">
        <option value="">Select Post</option>'; 
        foreach($items as $item) {
        echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$meta == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>'.$item->post_title.'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select></td>';
}else {
    echo '<td><select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">
        <option value="">Select Post</option>';
    echo '</select></td>';
}
break;
```

After troubleshooting my ajax I have some to the conclusion that this is where my issue is.

```
echo '<td><select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">
    <option value="">Select Post</option>';
echo '</select></td>';
```

I have tried getting the value through get_post_meta and get_options but I am obviously missing something.

How do you get the value from the database after saving.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `$item->ID` to `$meta` when your variable is called `$my_meta`.

Comment: I didn't post the full code as it is rather lengthy but  $meta is part of the system.

Comment: Okay, so how is the value being saved to the DB?  Can you show me that code and the code where $meta is populated?

Comment: Thank you. I have solved my issue by using metadata_exists.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it working by using an if statement with metadata_exists.

If anyone stumbles across this, here is the code I used.

```
}else {
    echo '<td><select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">';
        $saved_meta = metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID, 'ajax_destination' );
        if ( $saved_meta ) {
            $key_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ajax_destination', true );
            $the_key = get_post( $key_value ); 
            $title = $the_key->post_title;
            echo '<option value="'.$key_value.'">'.$title.'</option>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<option value="">Select Post</option>';
        }
    echo '</select></td>';
}
```